# How much time does the gravity field generated by a black hole singularity need to travel before exerting gravity forces on other celestial bodies?

Tags: gravity, time

It is known to all that the propagation of gravitational field is not instant.
So for black holes, the gravitational field generated by the singularity of the black holes needs time to travel before exerting gravitational pulling forces on other celestial bodies.
According to gravitational time dilation, the time near black holes are extremely dilated to infinity.
This indicates, given the limited age of the universe, the gravitational field generated by the singularity of any black holes have NOT exert any pulling forces on any celestial bodies yet.
Thus, we can conclude, it is impossible for any current celestial body to be pulled by the gravity of any black hole and orbit around a black hole. actually there should be no celestial bodies now gravitationally pulled by any black holes at all.
But, this conclusion is apparently absurd.
Any professor can explain this please?

Comment: Black hole does not appear from nothing, there is always matter that creates it. The gravity pull does not increase as the gravitational collapse happens.

Comment: *"gravitational field generated by the singularity"* what do you mean here?

Comment: Thank you for your kind comment. If we use high-energy lasar to create particles, these particles, once created, will generate gravitational fields, correct? And it is the same for all the object/celestial bodies/mass/energy, they all generate gravitational fields. This is my indication.

Comment: @Anixx Thank you very much for your kind answer. I am wondering whether the gravity pull will decrease as the gravitational collapse happens. For example, if electric charge materials fell into the event horizen during forming(collapsing) process of a black hole, the electric fields generated by the electric charge materials will decrease. So it is theoretically possible that gravity pull can also decrease.

Comment: You cannot create particles from nothing, if you use lasers to create particles, the energy in those lasers and beams already had gravitational pull.

Comment: @Anixx Thank you very much for your kind answer.True, it is commonly recognized that light has gravity field(bwt, do we have experimental proof about this? I didn't find any) Even if so, laser's gravity is laser's gravity, if we use laser beam to create an electron, then the electron's gravity is the electron's gravity. oncea  electron is created, it will generate its own gravity. Especially, according to current information, if we have 2 beams of paralel laser, one beam of laser wont feel gravity of the other beam until energy of the other beam are turned into electrons. Saying is thus valid.

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux Thank you very much for your kind comment. So now I have explained what was my indication in previous comments. Could you be so kind to answer the question now if possible?